# Problem with click function in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a link appended to a div element. And on clicking the link, I want a function to be executed.In order to check if the function is called, when I click the link, i had an alert box in that function. But no alert box is appearing if I click the link?

This is the link added to the div element 'fb`_`contentarea`_`col2top'.

```
$("<p class='title2'>Recent Entries | <a id='actions' href='#'>Actions</a> </p>").appendTo("#fb_contentarea_col2top");
```

When I click this link, I want this function to be called,

```
$('#actions').click(function (){
    alert("HI");

});
```

But the alert does not come. What is the mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to change "click" to live:

```
$("#actions").live("click", function() {
  alert("hi");
});
```

This will bind the actions to any #actions that presently exists, or will exist in the future. In your case, you're adding it in later.

Comment: ...or, bind the click event after you create the element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the script inside a document ready block. Else use .live outside the ready block.

```
$(function(){

  $('#actions').click(function (){
        alert("HI");

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#actions").bind('click', function() {
    alert("HI");
});
```

Comment: .bind and .live are slightly different: live binds to all future matches (which shouldn't be a problem, since id's should be unique).  I'm just more used to using .bind, which is why I suggested it.